# OSS dual licensing / market segregation

Tags: licensing, open-source, gpl

I have an open-source project, which I would like to commercially license to various types of businesses.

xGPL licenses do not work for me since they don't allow any conditional addenda.

What I'm seeking to achieve is:

- require commercial licensing for businesses
- allow use and changes under some OSS license for individuals
- allow free use (same as above) to specific business branches on individual selection basis (e.g. educational institutions).

I'm really confused about how to achieve this and don't violate the terms of the OSS part of license at the same time.

**Edit**: I'm looking for an existing free license, which doesn't explicitly forbid dual licensing like GPL family does.

Comment: If the license does not permit use for business, it's not an open source license under any commonly accepted definition of the word. Not even if you exempt some kinds of business. To quote a common definition from memory, open source licenses don't discriminate based on use case. There are of course licenses that only allow non-commercial use, but they're not open source or free as in free speech.

Comment: You seem not to understand that the copyright holder (that's you, if you wrote the software) is not beholden to any license terms on the software. You could release your own software under ten different licenses simultaneously and allow users to choose which particular license they want to receive it under. A license says "the copyright holder graciously allows you to have this software under these terms..." but that doesn't apply to you because you *are* the copyright holder and automatically have full rights to distribute it under any terms.

Comment: @apsillers please see Edit in the question

Comment: @Hardex How does the GPL forbid dual licensing? As far as I know, it doesn't.

Comment: @delnan GPL section 7 basically renders any additional requirements that are outside the GPL itself void.

Comment: @apsillers that could work, but the problem is that I don't want to let them choose a license themselves

Comment: @Hardex I am not a lawyer and can't really offer a more correct reading of that section, but note that Mozilla, Oracle, Qt, and others who employ lawyers *are* or were actively dual licensing with GPL (LGPL in the case of Qt) and a second license.

Comment: @Hardex Also I don't know why you dismiss apsiller's comment, he is correct and spot on. For example, section 7 allows (again, IANAL) someone who licenses the software under the terms of a GPL license from you to ignore "further restrictions" communicated alongside that license, but it does not prevent you from offering a different way to license the software (with proprietrary-esque requirements) and it does not prevent people from opting out of the GPL license and into that other license.

Comment: The problem with forbidding commercial use is that it is hard to define what constitutes commercial activity and what doesn't. Examples: Is a charity organization non-commercial when it sells cake to raise funds? Am I performing commercial activity when I use your software to design an ad to sell my old car? OK, maybe you say I am not allowed to use your software when I am being paid for it, but what if I use it in my spare-time to train for a job I expect to get paid for later?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are the copyright holder of the code, then you can provide the sources to different clients using different licenses. These licenses don't even need to be compatible with each other.

The common mode of dual licensing is that you provide two or more licensing options:

- a (L)GPL (or other copyleft) license for open source projects. The copyleft nature of the GPL ensures that it can't be used for closed-source projects (which most commercial ones still are).
- one or more commercial licenses for use in commercial/closed-source projects. You can vary the fee and license restrictions in any way you like (so a separate license for educational institutions is a possibility).

The thing to watch out for in dual-licensed projects is that you don't blindly accept contributions on your open source version.
Unless you get the copyright on contributions assigned to you, you can't move those contributions over from the open version to the commercially licensed versions, because you would be bound by the GPL license under which the contribution is made.
If the copyright has been assigned to you, then you are free to use the code as you see fit.

---

Using an open source license that allows sub-licensing means that anyone who gets a copy of your code can legally use it in a closed source project as well.
There are no open-source licenses that prohibit commercial use of the code, as that goes against the ideas behind open source code.